# Get the latest check in number (latest changeset id)

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

Is there a way to get programmatically latest changeset version in general.

It's fairly easy to get changeset id for certain file :

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://my.tfs.com/DefaultCollection"));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

and then call GetItems or QueryHistory, but i would like to know what was the last checkin number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var latestChangesetId =
    vcs.QueryHistory(
        "$/",
        VersionSpec.Latest,
        0,
        RecursionType.Full,
        String.Empty,
        VersionSpec.Latest,
        VersionSpec.Latest,
        1,
        false,
        true)
        .Cast<Changeset>()
        .Single()
        .ChangesetId;
```

Comment: It seems VersionControlServer also has a GetLatestChangesetId method. It is much shorter :-)

Comment: can we pass the username and pwd for below tfs connection 
`var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));
tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);`
bcoz after deploying my web pages to IIS server i m unable to get the tfs details but for localhost i m able to get the tfs details for same web pages.
i m getting below err
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/mycollection. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.ThrowAuthorizationException(Exception e)

Comment: @picnic4u probably best raising a new question for that.

Comment: @DaveShaw - i have tried below n working perfectly....
NetworkCrdential cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password","domain_name");
var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/mycollection", cred);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

Comment: How do you do it for a specific project or folder?  I changed "$/" to "$/MyProject1" and it worked, but if I change it to "$/MyProject2" it did not, it said there were no items in the collection.  In fact this only works on the project with the latest changeset in it.  How do you specify a range besides "latest - latest"?

Comment: I was able to make this work (and it's surprisingly performant even in projects that have several thousand changesets): 
`Console.WriteLine(vcs.QueryHistory("$/Project1/", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, null, VersionSpec.Latest, Int32.MaxValue, false, true).Cast<Changeset>().Select(cs => cs.ChangesetId).Max());`
 and 
`Console.WriteLine(vcs.QueryHistory("$/Project1/", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, null, VersionSpec.Latest, Int32.MaxValue, false, true).Cast<Changeset>().Select(cs => cs.ChangesetId).Max());`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`VersionControlServer.GetLatestChangesetId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getlatestchangesetid.aspx) to get the latest changeset id, as mentioned by user *tbaskan* in the comments.

<sub>(In the TFS Java SDK it's `VersionControlClient.getLatestChangesetId`)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I use following tf command for this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return last check-in History of a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">filename for which history is required</param>
    /// <returns>TFS history command</returns>
    private string GetTfsHistoryCommand(string filename)
    {
        //tfs history command (return only one recent record stopafter:1)
        return string.Format("history /stopafter:1 {0} /noprompt", filename);    // return recent one row
    }
```

after execution I parse the output of this command to get changeset number

```
    using (StreamReader Output = ExecuteTfsCommand(GetTfsHistoryCommand(fullFilePath)))
        {
            string line;
            bool foundChangeSetLine = false;
            Int64 latestChangeSet;
            while ((line = Output.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (foundChangeSetLine)
                {
                    if (Int64.TryParse(line.Split(' ').First().ToString(), out latestChangeSet))
                    {
                        return latestChangeSet;   // this is the lastest changeset number of input file
                    }
                }
                if (line.Contains("-----"))       // output stream contains history records after "------" row
                    foundChangeSetLine = true;
            }
        }
```

This how I execute the command

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes TFS commands by setting up TFS environment
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commands">TFS commands to be executed in sequence</param>
    /// <returns>Output stream for the commands</returns>
    private StreamReader ExecuteTfsCommand(string command)
    {
        logger.Info(string.Format("\n Executing TFS command: {0}",command));
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = _tFPath;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();                                               // wait until process finishes   
        // log the error if there's any
        StreamReader errorReader = process.StandardError;
        if(errorReader.ReadToEnd()!="")
            logger.Error(string.Format(" \n Error in TF process execution ", errorReader.ReadToEnd()));
        return process.StandardOutput;
    }
```

Not a efficient way but still a solution this works in TFS 2008, hope this helps.